# Button gotoScene not working

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

the `storyboard.gotoScene("facebook", "fade", 400)` is not working if i tap the button, and i dont get any error messages in the terminal. What am i doing wrong ?

```
-- requires 
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar ) 
_W = display.contentWidth; --Returns Screen Width
_H = display.contentHeight; --Returns Screen Height


local storyboard = require ("storyboard")
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

-- background

function scene:createScene(event)

    local screenGroup = self.view
    background = display.newImage("restart.png")
    screenGroup:insert(background)

    button = display.newImage("share2.png") 
    button.x = display.contentWidth / 2
    button.y = display.contentHeight -400
end

  function listener(event) 
    if event.phase == "began" then
          print(event.name.." occurred") 
        storyboard.gotoScene("facebook", "fade", 400)
    end
end 

function scene:enterScene(event)
    storyboard.purgeScene("game")
    button:addEventListener( "tap", listener ) 
end

function scene:exitScene(event)
    button:removeEventListener( "tap", listener ) 
end

function scene:destroyScene(event)
end

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)

return scene
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like corona does not like it when you call a Scene 'facebook' or renamed facebook to 'postmyscore' and it works

Answer (score 1):

The "tap" event and "touch" events are different and they get different "phases" passed to the event handler.  The way you have your event handler programmed, you're expecting "touch" events (began, ended, moved).  The tap event doesn't really generate any phases, either you were tapped or not.

Either change these two lines:

```
button:addEventListener( "tap", listener ) 
button:removeEventListener( "tap", listener )
```

to:

```
button:addEventListener( "touch", listener )
```

and

```
button:removeEventListener( "touch", listener )
```

or you can change your listner to:

```
function listener(event) 
    print(event.name.." occurred") 
    storyboard.gotoScene("facebook", "fade", 400)
end
```

Comment: Hi Rob, when i try both options i get : Runtime error ?:0: attempt to call method 'dispatchEvent' <a nil value>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
storyboard.gotoScene("facebook", {effect = "fade", time=400})
```

Or:

```
local options =
{
    effect = "fade",
    time = 400,
}

storyboard.gotoScene("facebook", options)
```

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/gotoScene.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since Coronas last update. I fixed the problem by removing the if check for the event phase. Just comment out the event.phase check in your listener function:

```
function listener(event) 
--if event.phase == "began" then
    print(event.name.." occurred") 
    storyboard.gotoScene("facebook", "fade", 400)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

facebook.lua is already integrated in the inbuild API , so it may generate the problem , more over you are using tap event , so in listener no need to check the phase or you may use touch event.